# Is it possible to have an implicit conversion between a Position(i, j) case class and 2D array indices?

Tags: arrays, scala, implicit-conversion

Let's say that I have a `board (`2D array) and the following class:

```
case class Position(i : Int, j : Int)
```

The typical scenario is to have something like this:

```
val v = board(position.i)(position.j)
```

which makes me wonder if it would in some way be possible to define an implicit conversion between my `Position` class and `board` so I could just write something like

```
val x = board(position)
```

Thanks

Comment: Is `board` a 2D array that you have created earlier that you are now trying to index into?

Comment: that's not how you should use implicits. Create a class for a board with an apply method that takes a position.

Comment: @Guillaume Massé: I'm not really interested in creating (yet another) class when the only thing I want is an easier way to access an array's elements. Were I to not use implicits, I'd favour creating a helper method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
implicit class IndexByPos(board: Array[Array[Int]]) {
    def apply(pos: Position) = board(pos.i)(pos.j)
}
```

I would note, though, that I agree with @GuillaumeMassé's comment - you will likely find it a lot more advantageous to define a specific class for board.